# How to find if an int value contains a specific number?

Tags: c

Odd question, but I'm currently working on an assignment where I am asked to do the following:

Write a program that prompts the user for an integer between 1 and 1000, then prints from 1 to the entered number EXCEPT when the following conditions are met:

If the current number is a multiple of 3 OR contains a 3, print "Hello"

if the current number is a multiple of 7 OR contains a 7, print "Goodbye"

I understand how to determine if a number is a multiple of 3 or 7, but how would I determine if it contained a 3 or 7? I have all of my code written except for this part, and I am just a little lost and unsure what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Code could print to a buffer using `sprintf()` and then search for the characters 3, 7 with `strchr()`.  Not elegant but meets the goal.

Comment: Personally I would do it with strings as @chux-ReinstateMonica says. But if you want to do pure integer operations then can use mod (`%`) and div (`/`) operations to get each digit. For example `x % 10` will get the least significant digit and `(x / 10) % 10` will get the next digit, etc. So just need a loop to extract each digit like that.

Comment: Hint: integer division by 10 with `/ 10` shifts the last decimal digit off, and the modulo operator with `% 10` gets the last decimal digit.

Comment: What are you supposed to do for 21 or 73?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, want to post that answer?

Comment: @DanielWalker No time now, Use it as you please.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mod `%` to find if somethings is dividable with 3 or 7.

To find the last digit of a number you should use mod 10 and then divide it by 10 to get the next digit.

The digits could also be obtained by using three nested loops from 0 to 10 with a break at final number or with a function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int contains(unsigned long num,int x){
   while(num){
      if(num % 10 == x){
         return 1;
      }
      num/=10;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(){
   printf("%d\n",contains(1237002,7));
   printf("%d\n",contains(10000002,7));
   printf("%d\n",contains(1234002,7));
   printf("%d\n",contains(123002,7));
   printf("%d\n",contains(7237002,7));
   printf("%d\n",contains(1237007,7));
   printf("%d\n",contains(7,7));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @chux-ReinstateMonica suggested, you could print the integer to a buffer and then search for the `'3'` and `'7'` characters.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool contains_3_or_7(int num) {
    char buffer[15];

    sprintf(buffer,"%i",num);
    return (strchr(buffer,'3') || strchr(buffer,'7'))
}
```

Comment: This is however a very inefficient algorithm. You can improve it slightly by swapping out the `strchr` calls for `strpbrk`. Still inefficient though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must split the 2 parts:

**First** with your `%` comparaison which determine if it's a multiple like `if (x % 7 == 0)` (0 means x is a multiple of 7)

and for the **seconde** part convert your int into an str with `itoa` function or by coding your own like this:

```
char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
char const digit[] = "0123456789";
char* p = b;
if(i<0){
    *p++ = '-';
    i *= -1;
}
int shifter = i;
do{ //Move to where representation ends
    ++p;
    shifter = shifter/10;
}while(shifter);
*p = '\0';
do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
    *--p = digit[i%10];
    i = i/10;
}while(i);
return b;
```

}

then you can determine for each condition if they are true or false